# How to validate using useEffect()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation

**I am trying to validate form using useState() and useEffect()**

*Here's my useEffect() method*:

```
/ for every change in our state this will be fired
  // we add validation here and disable the save button if required
  useEffect(() => {

    // we want to skip validation on first render
    if (firstRender.current) {
      firstRender.current = false
      return
    }

    // here we can disable/enable the save button by wrapping the setState function
    // in a call to the validation function which returns true/false
    //setDisabled(formValidation())
    formValidation();

  }, [fullName,email,password]) // any state variable(s) included in here will trigger the effect to run
```

`I am new to React JS so have done basic coding using if-else.
I am stuck in the concept here more than the technology.
**I am unable to validate other input fields such as email and password. How to achieve that?**
Here's my validation method:
// here we run any validation, returning true/false

```
  const formValidation = () => {
    var error = false;
    if (fullName === "") {
      setNameError('Name cant be blank!')
      error = true;
    }

    let regEmail = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    if (!regEmail.test.email) {
      setEmailError('Enter a valid email id')
      error = true;
    }
    if (email === "") {
      setEmailError('Mandatory Field')
      error = true;
    }
    let regPassword = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,15}$/
    if (!regPassword.test.email) {
      // alert("errosdr")
      setPasswordError('Invalid Password Format')
      error = true;
    }

    if (error == true) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      setNameError(null)
      setEmailError(null)
      setPasswordError(null)
      return false
    }
  }
```

The validation for the first field works well i.e. fullName.

Just for reference, here's the definition for useState()

```
    // we use the help of useRef to test if it's the first render
  const firstRender = useRef(true);

  // set a state variable which can be used to disable the save/submit button
  // we set it to true so that the form is disabled on first render
  const [disable, setDisabled] = useState(true);

  // set error messages to display to the user
  const [nameError, setNameError] = useState(null);
  const [emailError, setEmailError] = useState(null);
  const [passwordError, setPasswordError] = useState(null);

  // set initial state value(s)
  const [fullName, setFullName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
```

[image]

Comment: use `Formik` with `yup` library for easier validation a form handling.

Comment: @adel Thanks for informing. For now, wish to do it the normal way. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As soon as you call a set function in a component, it automatically re-renders. So in your case, `formValidation` calls `setNameError` and proceeds to re-rendering, thus the  rest of the code was not executed.

In your current implementation, this is what happened:

- `fullName`, `email`, or `password` is changed
- `formValidation()` is called
- checks if `fullName === ""` and calls `setNameError("Name can't be blank!")`
- component re-renders
- the rest of the logic in the function was not called.

To avoid this, you might want to store your error states in a single state:

```
const [errors, setErrors] = useState({})
```

The best practice is to only call a single `setState` in every function you create in every component. Ideally it is called after a certain logic.

Here is a sample modified `formValidation`

```
const formValidation = () => {
    let newErrors = {}
    if (fullName === "") {
      newErrors.name = 'Name cant be blank!'
    }

    let regEmail = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    if (!regEmail.test.email) {
      newErrors.email = 'Enter a valid email id'
    }
    if (email === "") {
      newErrors.email = 'Mandatory Field'
    }
    let regPassword = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,15}$/
    if (!regPassword.test.email) {
      newErrors.password = 'Invalid Password Format'
    }

    setErrors(newErrors)
  }
```

Comment: Make it ```{errors.password && <p>{errors.password}</p>}```

Comment: If it's helpful, mind making my answer as the best answer so it would help other readers. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @blankart for the quick response, resolved! Although, now working on email   regex not working as expected. Although, this issue is resolved! :)